# Shading Gap Between Lines in dygraph

Tags: r, dygraphs

I have been trying to shade the region between my two lines but instead the following code shades everything below the line despite trying to shade the series separately.

```
dygraph(newdata, main = "Distribution of Average Teacher Experience By Student URM,
School-Level Data")%>%
dyRangeSelector()%>%
dySeries("URM_exp", fillGraph=FALSE)%>%
dySeries("NonURM_Exp", fillGraph=TRUE)%>%
dyLegend(show = "follow")%>%
dyAxis("y", label = "Average Teacher Experience", valueRange = c(12, 15))%>%
```

I'd like to have a shaded region between the two lines to show the experience gap between under-represented minorities and non under-represented minority students.

Thank you.

Comment: could you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `dygraph` feature for drawing upper/lower bars (see [here](https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-upper-lower-bars.html)).

You just need to add some "fake" new series that make the lower/upper bound of your data. In your case that is copying both series `NonURM_Exp` and `URM_exp`. Then, instead of plotting both series individually, you plot one triple series, like explained in the link to the dygraph page above. This way, a shaded region gets plotted (between both series, because the bounds were exactly those) in the color of the triple series.

Code below:

```
library(dygraphs)

# Some mock data.
newdata <- data.frame(
  row.names = seq(Sys.Date(), length.out = 10, by = "1 day"),
  URM_exp = sample(seq(14, 15, 0.01), 10),
  NonURM_Exp = sample(seq(12, 14, 0.01), 10)
)

# Make up some border series.
newdata$border1 <- newdata$URM_exp
newdata$border2 <- newdata$NonURM_Exp

# One single + one triple series do the trick.
dygraph(newdata, main = "Distribution of Average Teacher Experience By Student URM, School-Level Data")%>%
  dyRangeSelector() %>%
  dySeries("NonURM_Exp") %>%
  dySeries(c("border2", "URM_exp" , "border1")) %>%
  dyLegend(show = "follow") %>%
  dyAxis("y", label = "Average Teacher Experience", valueRange = c(12, 15))
```